# Django - No Module named 'django'

Tags: django

I recently installed Django and below is the installation path

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Python Software Foundation\Python\Lib\site-packages\

I added the path to the PATH environment variable and I tried `django-admin` command in the cmd prompt. I am getting the below error:

> 'django-admin' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

Whereas if I go into the django's bin folder and issue the same `django-admin` command, I am getting the below error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python Software Foundation\Python\Lib\site-packag
>   es\django\bin\django-admin.py", line 2, in 
>       from django.core import management
>   ImportError: No module named 'django'

All I want is for Django to create a website for me inside the project folder that I have created. Any help on how to fix this will help me started with Django.

Comment: have  you installed django globally? and Which OS are you using?

Comment: I assume you are on windows. Is the path there (type path in the command prompt)?

Comment: I am on Windows 7..When I type echo %PATH% I am able to see the django path present

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to install django within virtual environment.

**Follow these steps for ubuntu:**

1. Choose/make a folder mkdir DjangoProjects
2. Inside that folder install virtualenv by:

   pip install virtualenv .
3. Active environment as:

   source ./bin/activate
4. Install Django as :

   pip install django

It will install the latest version of django

Now You can verify that the installation was successful by typing:

```
django-admin --version
```

It must show :
    1.10.5

For **windows OS** read follow this tut: https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/installation/